# Loading a specific data-role="page" when jsp loads - jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jsp, web-applications, jquery-mobile

I am developing a mobile web application with jquery mobile. I have various div pages in a jsp file, and when that file loads I want a specific page to load. I am using

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href.split('#')[0] + '#directory_page')
```

however div page loads only after the page has been refreshed.

any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you give us a bit more code ?

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself.. didn't read the documentation properly. I needed to add rel="external" to the link that sends me to the multipage... first page loads automatically